# How to make this json using java

Tags: java, json

I want to create this json using java ,somebody help

```
{
 "comment": "Check out developer.linkedin.com!",
 "content": {
   "title": "LinkedIn Developers Resources",
   "description": "Leverage LinkedIn's APIs to maximize engagement",
   "submitted-url": "https://developer.linkedin.com",  
"submitted-image-url": "https://example.com/logo.png"
 },
 "visibility": {
  "code": "anyone"
}  
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate more on this? Also, show us what you have tried so far. One liner answer to this question would be - create your Java objects as per the JSON structure and use JSON-Java (and vice versa) conversion library (eg. GSON).

Comment: Have you tried something? Can you post it please?

Comment: I'd suggest a googling on how to use FasterXML's Jackson datamapper

Answer (score 0):

1. Create java class to map to Json..something like

   ```
   public class JavaClass  {
   private String comment;
    // other Can be in map or java class for content
   private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    //getters and setters
   }
   ```
2. populate the object and use any library to convert to Json object.

   ```
    JavaClass  object = new JavaClass ();
    object.set(....)
   ```
3. Now using [JSONbject](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html)

   ```
    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject( object );
    System.out.println( jsonObj );
   ```

Answer (score 0):

```
try{
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        jsonObject.put("comment", "Check out developer.linkedin.com!");
        JSONObject contentJsonObject = new JSONObject();
        contentJsonObject.put("title", "LinkedIn Developers Resources");
        contentJsonObject.put("description", "Leverage LinkedIn's APIs to maximize engagement");
        contentJsonObject.put("submitted-url", "https://developer.linkedin.com");
        contentJsonObject.put("submitted-image-url", "https://example.com/logo.png!");
        jsonObject.put("content",contentJsonObject);
        JSONObject visibilityJsonObject = new JSONObject();
        visibilityJsonObject.put("code", "anyone");
        jsonObject.put("visibility",visibilityJsonObject);
    }catch(JSONException ex){
        Log.i("json ex: ",ex.toString());
    }
```